# multiple languages in the same project in Intellij idea

Tags: java, actionscript-3, sdk, intellij-idea

In intellij IDEA, I am working with Java & ActionScript in the same project. The Java SDK is the default of the project. When I want to program in ActionScript, several classes are not available (eg. String). The former point happens because the project is not using the ActionScript SDK, I guess. Then my question is: Is it to possible use multiple languages (two in this case) in the same IntelliJ IDEA project? If the answer is "Yes", then How can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your ActionScript classes are in a separate module, you can change the SDK which is used for that module in `Project Settings > Modules > yourModule > Dependencies tab > Module SDK`.

Of course, you don't have to change the SDK for your Java module (it will remain JDK xyz).

Comment: Thanks, I love stackoverflow

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted and/or vote for it if it solved your problem (for future readers).

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if this is what you are looking for, still give it a try.

http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/concepts/index.html

Comment: That's for meta programming: custom DSL's.  What is the relevance - maybe be more clear.