# Setting python interpreter in intellij in a multi language (scala/java/python) module

Tags: python, intellij-idea

As shown in the following screenshot the python 2.7.2 sdk is configured

[image]

Also:

- the python facet was added to module "spark-parent"
- the "python" directory was added as a source root

But as you can see all of the standard python imports are failing. Note that the *custom* spark python ('pyspark') classses ARE resolved.[image]

In response to the answer from Dwight Brown: changing the Project SDK away from java to python does not work in this mixed project: see screenshot below

[image]

Comment: @Victor I deleted the pycharm tag since I am using the python plugin in intellij and not pycharm. I guess they are more different than anticipated.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment for nothing :/ Idea? I don't know then, never tried to use python under idea..

Comment: @VictorPolevoy  It generally works very well. Just wonderful. This particular project is a bit complicated to configure.

Comment: We are going offtopic here, but you interested me in making some research..

Comment: SGTM  sounds good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem.

After some tries I found this solution

1. create a just empty module named `java-dep-python` etc then add it to project

   ```
   <module relativePaths="false" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
     <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
       <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Python 2.7" jdkType="Python SDK" />
       <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
     </component>
   </module>
   ```
2. change all your mixed modules to add this new empty module as dependency

   ```
   <module relativePaths="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
     <component name="FacetManager">
       <facet type="Python" name="Python">
         <configuration sdkName="Python 2.7" />
       </facet>
     </component>
     <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
       ... ...
       <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
       <orderEntry type="module" module-name="java-dep-python" scope="PROVIDED" />
       ... ...
     </component>
   </module>
   ```

Note that the `PROVIDED` keyword do help that this module is not required by any artifacts

It works for me, now that standard python imports are good.

IDEA 14.0.3 build #IU-139.1117

Answer (score 4):

almost there, the only thing you were missing is to set the Python interpreter for the actual facet. I had to restart Intellij in order for things to actually apply.

[image]

Comment: you had to restart intellij?  that might be what I were missing. That's pretty extreme.

Answer (score 2):

the Project SDK needs to be set as well 'Command ;' and set the Project SDK to python SDK you intend to use.

This might be of some help as well.
[multiple languages in the same project in Intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401694/multiple-languages-in-the-same-project-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: For Project | Project SDK it is set to Java 1.7  That is not where python SDK is supposed to be set. Do you have more details or another suggestion?

Comment: Well I am trying this to set Project | Project SDK to Python 2.7.2  This has obvious disadvantage: breaks all the scala/java code. Do you have any comments or improvements on this?

Comment: Did you try the link for multiple languages?

Comment: For this project we  need both python and scala/java in the SAME modules. That link talks about single-language modules.